# Android background color for accordion menu

Tags: java, android, button, background

I want the code in the Java file to set the background color of whatever button was clicked, and keep it, even after you let go of the button. Thanks in advance

I don't really get the formatting on here. I hope it's clear what belongs where.

Java:

```
 package mika.actual;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class accordion extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.accordian);

        Button btnProfile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnProfile);
        Button btnSettings = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSettings);
        Button btnPrivacy = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPrivacy);

        View panelProfile = findViewById(R.id.panelProfile);
        panelProfile.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        View panelSettings = findViewById(R.id.panelSettings);
        panelSettings.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        View panelPrivacy = findViewById(R.id.panelPrivacy);
        panelPrivacy.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        btnProfile.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // DO STUFF
                View panelProfile = findViewById(R.id.panelProfile);
                panelProfile.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                View panelSettings = findViewById(R.id.panelSettings);
                panelSettings.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                View panelPrivacy = findViewById(R.id.panelPrivacy);
                panelPrivacy.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        });

        btnSettings.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // DO STUFF
                View panelProfile = findViewById(R.id.panelProfile);
                panelProfile.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                View panelSettings = findViewById(R.id.panelSettings);
                panelSettings.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                View panelPrivacy = findViewById(R.id.panelPrivacy);
                panelPrivacy.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        });

        btnPrivacy.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // DO STUFF
                View panelProfile = findViewById(R.id.panelProfile);
                panelProfile.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                View panelSettings = findViewById(R.id.panelSettings);
                panelSettings.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                View panelPrivacy = findViewById(R.id.panelPrivacy);
                panelPrivacy.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        });

    }

}
```

XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnProfile"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Profile"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/panelProfile"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFFFFFFF">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#FFFFFFFF">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/panelProfile1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#FFFFFFFF">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/strName"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Name" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/txtName"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>


                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/panelProfile2"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#FFFFFFFF">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/strSurname"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Surname" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/txtSurname"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSettings"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Settings"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/panelSettings"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FFFFFFFF">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/panelSettings1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#FFFFFFFF">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/strMail"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="e-mail" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/txtMail"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/panelSettings2"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#FFFFFFFF">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/strPhone"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Phone" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/txtPhone"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPrivacy"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Privacy"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/panelPrivacy"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FFFFFFFF">

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkFacebook"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Facebook"
                android:textColor="#ff355689">
            </CheckBox>
            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkLinkedIn"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="LinkedIn"
                android:textColor="#ff355689">
            </CheckBox>
            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkTwitter"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Twitter"
                android:textColor="#ff355689">
            </CheckBox>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Did you consider using a selector?

Comment: You basically want to have a selected/unselected state, is that it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, what you want to do is, when clicking a button and expanding its sub-menu, change the background of that button until it is clicked again. You can do this with a Tag on the Button:

```
btnSettings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // DO STUFF
        //if button is not selected, change background and tag the View as selected
        if(v.getTag() == null || v.getTag().equals("not_selected")) {
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            v.setTag("selected");
            //show sub-menu
        }
        //if button is already selected, reset background and tag the View as not selected
        else{
            v.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
            v.setTag("not_selected");
            //hide sub menu
        }

    }
});
```

Notice that `v.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);` is resetting the Button background to an android drawable. You may want to change this to a custom drawable or color.
You could have used an `ExpandableListView` to implement this kind of menu.

Comment: Thanks. I'm fairly new to this, so thanks for the tips. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.presed_color));
                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.unpresed_color));
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```